# Flask-Login login_user() show encrypted cookie from Set-Cookie header

Tags: python, flask, cookies, flask-login

I am struggling with getting encoded, signed cookie from returned response at an endpoint where I had called `login_user(my_user)` before.
I was testing that code with *curl -v* each time - in the console I see `< Set-Cookie: session=.eJwdjjkOAyEMAP9CncI2YMx...`, but nothing printed by Python...

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "abcd"


class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, identificator):
        self.identificator = identificator

    def get_id(self) -> int:
        return int(self.identificator)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get_id(user_id)


@app.after_request
def ar(resp):
    print(resp.headers.getlist("Set-Cookie")) # empty [] list here instead of cookies

    return resp


@app.route("/test")
def test():
    user = User(1234)
    login_user(user)

    return "something"
```

**How to get the cookie (result of the `login_user()` call) which is going to be sent to the user?**

Comment: What do you need the cookie for? Do you want to log it? If so, why?

Comment: Store it in my database as session verification in the future (maybe its hash or something) - I could revoke others session remotely.
Nonetheless - do not take my thinking as wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

The session is signed at the end of the response flow.

In my opinion there are two approaches you can take:

- Create custom Flask application instance and extend the following method `def process_response(self, response: Response) -> Response:` to do the logic you need - see [source](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/44bc286c03ff3f8e783b4f79f75eb3a464940ca0/src/flask/app.py#L1888) to check exactly how the signing happens.
- Create custom WSGI middleware and process that there - see [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#hooking-in-wsgi-middleware) for context.